# Probability that a draw from a normal distribution is some number greater than another draw from the same distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I hope to learn the general way of solving this problem, but I have this specific problem:
$$
X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) \\
\mu=470,\ \sigma=70
$$
If two people, A and B, each draw one entry from the same distribution, what is the probability that A's entry is at least 100 more than B's entry?

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent random variables both with distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. What is the distribution of the random variable $A-B$?

Comment: You have $A-B>100$. Rearrange to $A-B-100>0$. Now all you have to do is figuring out the distribution of $A-B-100$. In this case, this is [quite easy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_normal_deviates) (hint: it's still a normal distribution).

Comment: Hint: $A-B$ is also a normal random variable. Can you figure out what the mean and variance of $A-B$ are? If so, you should be able to answer the question; What is the probability that $A-B$ is $100$ or more?

Answer (score 15):

Since it looks like `self-study` question, I'll start with a hint: Think of $X_1-X_2$ with
$X_1, X_2 \sim N(470, 70^2)$. What distribution does $X_1-X_2$ follow? How to interpret $X_1-X_2$?